# Adding scrollview to a layout section when it is taking too much height from another section

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android, scrollview

EDIT: With the suggested answer i get this result:
[image]
History layout has a listview that has a height to match parent and i think this creates some problems, is there any workaround to this?
The new code that shows History layout hidden is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/ParentLayoutPadding"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/Layout_Main">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SearchNumbersScrollView"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/HistoryLinearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SearchNumbersLinearLayout"
            android:elevation="@dimen/ParentLayoutElevation"
            android:background="@drawable/ResourceOptionsBorderWithoutTopPadding"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/SearchNumbersTitleRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    style="@style/MyCategoryTitleTextStyle"
                    android:text="@string/Menu_DrawSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/PaidDescriptionTextView"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ShowInstructionsImageButton"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/MinimumItemSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/MinimumItemSize"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/normalTextColorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_info_layer"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/Common_InformationIconContentDescription" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/LineMargin"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/CategoryLineHeight"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <include
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/SelectDateRange"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                        android:padding="@dimen/CategoryTitlePadding"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_NumbersTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/ListNameTextView" />
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/ListTextView"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/CategoryTitlePadding"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ListNameTextView"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ListNameTextView"
                        android:hint="@string/NumbersSearch_NumbersHint"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:maxLines="2" />
                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        style="@style/AppTheme.GrayButtonStyle"
                        android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_NumberSelectionButtonTitle"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/CategoryTitlePadding"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/OptionsTextView"
                        android:id="@+id/SelectNumbersButton"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="left">
                    <CheckBox
                        style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                        android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_SearchPerNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CheckboxMarginTopBottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CheckboxMarginTopBottom"
                        android:id="@+id/SeperateCheckBox"
                        android:buttonTint="@color/buttonColorPrimary"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/CheckBoxPadding" />
                    <CheckBox
                        style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                        android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_IncludeDrawTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CheckboxMarginTopBottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CheckboxMarginTopBottom"
                        android:id="@+id/ShowListsCheckBox"
                        android:buttonTint="@color/buttonColorPrimary"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/CheckBoxPadding" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/SearchTypeLinearLayout"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/SelectDate"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/CategoryTitlePadding"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/CategoryTitlePadding"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                            android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_ShowResultsTitle"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/ShowResultsTitleTextView"
                            android:minLines="1"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:gravity="left" />
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/ShowResultsSpinner"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ShowResultsTitleTextView"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/SelectDate"
                            android:ellipsize = "none"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ShowResultsTitleTextView"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/SpinnerPaddingStartEnd"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/SpinnerPaddingTopBottom"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/SpinnerPaddingTopBottom"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/SpinnerPaddingTopBottom"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ShowResultsTitleTextView" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/AppTheme.ButtonStyle"
                android:elevation="@dimen/ButtonElevation"
                android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_ButtonSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/OptionsTextView"
                android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include
    android:id="@+id/HistoryLinearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SearchNumbersScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        layout="@layout/HistoryLinearLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**HistoryLinearLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/MinimumHistoryLayoutHeight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HistoryLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/HistoryPadding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HistoryTitleTextView"
            style="@style/MyTextStyle"
            android:text="@string/Common_HistoryWithColon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/ParentLayoutPadding"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/AppTheme.GrayButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/NumbersSearch_Clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/OptionsTextView"
            android:id="@+id/ClearHistoryButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/HistoryListView"
            android:background="@drawable/ListViewBackground"
            android:layout_below="@id/HistoryLinearLayout"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:divider="@color/BackgroundColor"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="nav_header_height">176dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>

  <!-- common dimens -->
  <dimen name="small_50">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="small_100">8dp</dimen>
  <!-- 50% of normal = 8dp -->

  <dimen name="normal_100">16dp</dimen>
  <!-- 100% of normal = 16dp -->
  <dimen name="normal_125">20dp</dimen>
  <!-- 125% of normal = 16dp + 4dp = 20dp -->
  <dimen name="normal_150">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_175">28dp</dimen>

  <dimen name="normal_200">32dp</dimen>
  <!-- normal_200 = 2 x normal_100 -->
  <dimen name="normal_225">36dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_250">40dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_275">44dp</dimen>

  <dimen name="normal_300">48dp</dimen>
  <!-- normal_300 = 3 x normal_100 -->
  <dimen name="normal_325">52dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_350">56dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_375">60dp</dimen>

  <dimen name="large_100">32dp</dimen>
  <!-- large_100 = 2 x normal_100 -->
  <dimen name="large_125">40dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="large_150">48dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="large_175">56dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="large_200">64dp</dimen>

  <!-- ResourceLayout -->
  <dimen name="ImageViewResourceLayout">60dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ImageViewResourceLayoutPadding">7dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsMarginInsideCards">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsMarginBetweenCards">12dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsButtonOrSwitchMargin">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsMarginBetweenLinearLayouts">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsMarginFromScreen">12dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsTextSize">14dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="LineHeight">2dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CategoryLineHeight">1dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="LineMarginTopBottom">10dp</dimen>
  <!-- OptionsLayout -->
  <dimen name="OptionsSwitchPadding">11dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="RestorePurchasePadding">11dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="AutoCloseEditextWidth">60dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CurrentColorSize">36dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ResourceOptionsLineMarginForCategory">60dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="TemplatesSpinnerHeight">112dp</dimen>
  <!-- SearchScreenLayout -->
  <dimen name="ImageButtonMargin">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="StatisticsHeight">60dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ElementPaddingTopBottom">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ElementPaddingParentBottom">15dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SwitchPadding">11dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SearchMargin">11dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumbersFrequencySpinnerPadding">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumberSelectionPaddingTop">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumberSelectionPaddingPadding">1dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumberSelectionSize">30dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumberSelectionCornerRadius">15dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="NumberSelectionPaddingRight">4dp</dimen>
  <!-- OptionsLayout -->
  <dimen name="PortMargin">8dp</dimen>
  <!-- StatisticsLayout -->
  <dimen name="OptionsSpinnerWidth">170dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="EditTextMargin">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="PasswordEditTextMargin">8dp</dimen>
  <!-- StatisticsLayout PerformanceTrend-->
  <dimen name="PerformanceScoreSize">160dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="PerformanceTrendHeight">200dp</dimen>
  <item format="float" name="LabelTextSize" type="dimen">40</item>
  <item format="float" name="LineSize" type="dimen">10</item>
  <item format="float" name="MaxValue" type="dimen">100</item>
  <!-- Common -->
  <dimen name="SpinnerHeight">40dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="MinimumHistoryLayoutHeight">150dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="HistoryPadding">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="IconSize">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ButtonIconSize">20dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ParentLayoutPadding">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="AlertDialogPadding">12dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SpinnerPaddingStartEnd">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SpinnerPaddingTopBottom">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CategoryTitlePadding">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CheckboxMarginTopBottom">3dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CategoryMarginTop">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="CategoryMarginBottom">5dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="CategoryMarginTopBottom">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="CategorySeperatorMarginTopBottom">12dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SelectDateMarginRight">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ParentLayoutElevation">1dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ButtonMargin">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="ButtonElevation">2dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="TwoLineText">2</dimen>
  <dimen name="UnlockDateRangeMargin">12dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="IconButtonSize">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="IconButtonMargin">14dp</dimen>
  <!-- OddEvenDelays -->
  <dimen name="CheckBoxPadding">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="BetPerRawWidth">50dp</dimen>
  <!-- Info -->
  <dimen name="ProbabilityMargin">5dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="PercentageTopMargin">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="SpinnerWidth">130dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**ListViewBackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightBackgroundColor" />
```

**ResourceOptionsBorderWithoutTopPadding.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightBackgroundColor" />
    <solid android:color="@color/lightBackgroundColor" />
</shape>
    <solid android:color="@color/lightBackgroundColor" />
</shape>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NumberPicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerItemStyle</item>
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

  <style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>    <!--header background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/lightBackgroundColor</item>    <!--calendar background-->
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>    <!--selected day-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>    <!--days of the month-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>    <!--days of the week-->
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.ButtonStyle" parent ="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <!-- Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/buttonColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">3dp</item>
  </style>
<style name="AppTheme.OutlinedButtonStyle" parent ="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
<!-- Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored -->
  <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">48dp</item>
  <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/WhiteTextColorSelector</item>
  <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <!-- <item name="cornerRadius">3dp</item> -->
</style>
  <style name="AppTheme.GrayButtonStyle" parent ="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <!-- Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/BasicTextColorSelector</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">3dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.WhiteButtonStyle" parent ="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <!-- Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/WhiteTextColorSelector</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">3dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.IconButtonStyle" parent ="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <!-- Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">3dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="NumberSelectionAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CommonAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/buttonColorPrimaryLight</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CommonAlertDialogSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerCommonAlertDialogItemStyle</item>
  </style>
<style name="MyTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
<item name="android:textColor">@drawable/BasicTextColorSelector</item>
  <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/normalTextColorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/buttonColorPrimary</item>
</style>
  <style name="MyCategoryTitleTextStyle" parent="MyTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CommonAlertDialogTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Spinner style -->
  <style name="spinnerCommonAlertDialogItemStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
  <!-- Spinner style drop down style-->
  <style name="spinnerCommonAlertDialogDropDownItemStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
  <!-- Spinner style -->
  <style name="spinnerItemStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:gravity">left</item>-->
     <!-- <item name="android:textAlignment">left</item>-->
  </style>

  <!-- Spinner style drop down style-->
  <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/SpinnerPaddingStartEnd</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/SpinnerPaddingStartEnd</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
  </style>
  
  <style name="CategoryTitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" >
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
  </style>
  
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

</resources>
```

which looks like this in phones with 1080p resolution:
[image: Layout]

My problem is this:
the blue box from the image (HistoryLinearLayout) is smaller screens appears too small, i would like to have a minimum height of 150sp ( i have try to add minHeight in the HistoryLinearLayout but it doesnt do anything) and the yellow section from the image to be scrollable when that happen, so if the yellow section doesnt fit and at the same time the HistoryLinearLayout to be at least 150sp, the yellow section to appear with scrollbar.

Right now it doesnt work, the scroll bar doesnt do anything and the minHeight is not being respected.

So in other words what i want is this: if blue section (HistoryLinearLayout) is less than 150sp, make it 150sp and make the yellow section (ScrollView) scrollable. i dont mind if this can be happen by code also.

Comment: The code is not completed, i could not reproduce.  Based on my test, the scrollview would scroll when the elements inside out of the height. Could you provide the code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Wendy thanks, so in your tests the history layout was always visible and if there was not enough space the scrollview was stretching the content? Strange in my tests the scrollview is like it is not exist and the history layout can appear very tiny. I will provide code later

Comment: Waiting for your code.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT i have update the code with all the layout files

Answer (score 1):

Constraint let you build flexible layout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#aa3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/blue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#33f"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bbb"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: preview]

If you set both scroll and blue to `layout_height="0dp"`, they always share even space.

Comment: i always felt that settings layout_height="0dp" is somehow a hack and that tere should be another better way around it but i see we still need it, thanks

Comment: it doesnt work in my case cause i have a listview in the history layout that is hidden if i use your code and set android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the blue, do we have any workaround for this? i have also include the historylinearlayout in the question and have update the main layout file with your suggestion

Comment: 0dp is not a hack in ConstraintLayout. It means "height is defined from constraints". If wrap_content, it means "height is at least wrap but consider constraints". If you are OK with static height for blue, try "0dp" for blue. It evens both area.